# building custom redis client

Tags: c, redis, hiredis

I've build a custom redis-client using hiredis library, but while compiling it throws below error:

```
example.c:4:10: fatal error: hiredis.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <hiredis.h>
```

Need help in resolving this issue.

*(may be out of conext)*
I also want to know why these people don't write proper documentation for it, there is not single page explaining how to install hiredis and build it, there are sites or some other tutorials telling those steps but it should come from official one. so we can know we are on the right path.

Comment: There is no "C/C++" language, only the two distinct and very different C language and C++ language. Please pick *one* of them. Once you've done that, read documentation and tutorials related to Redis and the chosen language. Then try something yourself.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And when you have a specific and rather narrow problem you need help with, you're more than welcome back here to ask about it, providing an [mcve] showcasing your problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok i will read about redis, but there are so many topics under redis section , i don't get which one will help and save time. can you mention the topic/subsection under redis  which will be relaated to the question

Comment: You probably would want to search for the term: non-blocking and redis. I think you can do exactly what you want without writing a custom client.

Comment: From C++ (or C, either language) nearly everyone starts with hiredis in understanding how redis interaction works. Further, many/most of the class libraries and tool kits use that library as their access core to interacting with redis servers. The [redis protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) is not complicated whatsoever, intentionally designed to be usable from just about any language. so foregoing a canned redis client library and rolling you own is certainly feasible, though you'll ultimately have to make the call on whether it is something you want to undertake and maintain.

Comment: @WhozCraig and all i updated the question to ask some error .please answer if you know how to resolve this or any idea what might be the issue

Comment: The issue is the hiredis include folder is not part of your include path. Hiredis, btw, is not part of the "official" redis server build support. It started as a basic C contrib and evolved into the most common API for accessing redis servers from C or C++ code, so much so that many redis distros actuall include it. You may find pulling a fork of the git-managed hiredis project, and/or at least perusing their documentation, more informative. You can find it [here](https://github.com/redis/hiredis/tree/v1.0.0). (the 1.0 release is at that link).

Comment: @WhozCraig https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771884/custom-redis-client-compilation-failing  look here. I've posted it as a new question.

Comment: and I think i found the solution but i do not know how to use it in my case: see here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979295/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-fi