# custom redis-client compilation failing

Tags: c, redis, compilation, fatal-error, hiredis

I've build a custom redis-client using hiredis library, but while compiling it throws below error:

```
example.c:4:10: fatal error: hiredis.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <hiredis.h>
```

Need help in resolving this issue.

How did i build hiredis:

1. downloaded v1.0.0 from https://github.com/redis/hiredis/releases
2. cd hiredis_directory
3. make
4. sudo make install

compiled the client using command :

1. `gcc redis_client.c -o rc -lhiredis`
2. `gcc -o rc redis_client.c -lhiredis $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0)`
3. `gcc redis_client.c -o rc`

Each one of them is giving the same error.

Comment: If you used a default target folder (chances are you did), then the hiredis headers will be put in something like `/usr/local/include/hiredis`, which needs to be added to your include path. I.e. `-I /usr/local/include/hiredis` should be in each one of those build lines. The target default install dir varies from platform to platform, so pay attention to your `sudu make install` command results. It will show you where everything was put. You may have to add a `-L` library path addendum as well. Fyi, I don't use pkgconfig, but chances are you can use it to get the include path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>
```

and run the same commands.
Also, you can make sure that 'hiredis' is present at */usr/local/include* path (make install does that for you BTW).